# RxBluetoothKit documentation?

Tags: swift, rxiosble

I'm trying out [RxBluetoothKit](https://github.com/Polidea/RxBluetoothKit) and one of the bullet point features is "Documentation", but the link for that leads to [a page](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxBluetoothKit/3.0.1/) which is just a copy of the README with a sidebar saying "Error Parsing Pod Could not find Objective-C Classes."

The README is quite detailed, and the sample code is useful, but an API reference would be nice for the more tricky details. For example, the README has an example with this code:

```
peripheral.connect()
.flatMap { $0.discoverServices([serviceId]) }
```

I have no idea what type `serviceId` is - I presume it's not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the documentation is written above the methods so while typing discoverServices in Xcode you should be able to click on method with options key and little popup will come up with formatted documentation. Our doc is formatted by the CocoaDocs - it appears that it has some problems. I'm working on fixing it - here you can find the issue [Github issue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxBluetoothKit/issues/88)

Answer (score 0):

And here you could find proper link to documentation: [RxBluetoothKit documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxBluetoothKit/3.0.6/index.html)